# Convert List Pairs to Key Value Pairs in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

This `poll = ['Kassel', 33, 'Berlin', 25, 'Hamburg', 23]` should convert to `{'Kassel': 33, 'Berlin': 25, 'Hamburg': 23}`.

This works:

```
location = poll[::2]
result = poll[1::2]
poll = dict(zip(location, result))
```

Is there a faster, more pythonic way to pair values in a list of length n?

Answer (score 2):

A dict comprehension like this would do:

```
{poll[i]: poll[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(poll), 2)}
```

Comment: While it works... I'd find it difficult to argue it's more Pythonic or faster...

Comment: No arguments there.